# How do I hide .txt files from being seen on my website

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website which logs the users activity on a text file. But then when I enter www.mywebsite.com/textfile.txt  I can clearly see the contents of that txt file. How do I hide this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this rewrite in top of .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^textfile\.txt$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Or use directive Files:

```
<Files "textfile.txt">  
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

And for Apache 2.4+, use this:

```
<Files "textfile.txt">  
  Require all denied
</Files>
```